# iOS 9 PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL: fails with error code -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios9, phphotolibrary

I'm using below code to save a video to photo library.

```
NSString *ss = [finalVideoURL path];

    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;


    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest* createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ss]];
        _placeholder = [createAssetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
        {

            NSLog(@" success iOS 9");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

This code works well with `iOS 8.x.` 
But it fails with error code -1 in `iOS 9.x`. 
The error is

```
`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"`
```

Any idea about this behavior in iOS 9.?
Any help is appreciated !
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only save in your own album 
 You need to create a photo album

```
//获取自定义相册
- (PHAssetCollection *)getAPPCollection {
// Getting the app album if any: 找是否已经创建自定义相册
PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection *> *collectionResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
for (PHAssetCollection *collection in collectionResult) {
    if ([collection.localizedTitle isEqualToString:appName]) {
        return collection;
    }
}

// Creating the album: 新建自定义相册
__block NSString *collectionId = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChangesAndWait:^{
    collectionId = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:appName].placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection.localIdentifier;
} error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"创建相册：%@失败", appName);
    return nil;
}
return [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[collectionId] options:nil].lastObject;
}
```

Comment: Please make proper indentation of your code ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks